# How to sort order of an array with dictionaries in ios

Tags: ios, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary, alphabetical

i have an array in such manner.

```
rows1 (
    "Adam Harris",
    "Devraj Singh",
    "Devraj Singh",
    "Er Devraj Gurjar",
    "Ghh HHS",
    "Mark Json",
    "Ninehertz India",
    "Ninehertz India",
    "Test User",
    "Test Test",
    "Yatin TFT"
)
```

I have used below code

```
NSArray *rows = ...;
    NSMutableDictionary *map = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSString *value in rows) {
        NSString *firstLetter = [value substringToIndex:1];
        if (!map[firstLetter]) {
            map[firstLetter] = @[];
        }
        NSMutableArray *values = [map[firstLetter] mutableCopy];
        [values addObject:value];
        map[firstLetter] = values;
    }
    NSArray *finalRows = [map allValues];
```

To sort the Array in alphabetical order. There would be two conditions in sorting 1.) all the words starts with same alphabet should be grouped which I have achieved as shown in the below array. Now my problem is that I want to arrange all the grouped items in alphabetical order. 2.) all the grouped elements of array now should be sorted in alphabetical order. Below is what I have achieved.

```
 (
            (
            "Devraj Singh",
            "Devraj Singh"
        ),
            (
            "Mark Json"
        ),
            (
            "Er Devraj Gurjar"
        ),
            (
            "Adam Harris"
        ),
            (
            "Ninehertz India",
            "Ninehertz India"
        ),
            (
            "Test User",
            "Test Test"
        ),
            (
            "Ghh HHS"
        ),
            (
            "Yatin TFT"
        )
    )
```

And What I want to do is as below

```
(
                (
                "A1",
                "A2"
            ),
                (
                "B1"
            ),
                (
                "C1"
            ),
                (
                "D1"
            ),
                (
                "E1",
                "E2",
                "E3"
            ),
                (
                "F1",
                "F2"
            ),
                (
                "G1"
            ),
                (
                "H1"
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to change your last line to this:

```
NSArray *finalRows = [[map allValues] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSString *letter1 = [obj1[0] substringToIndex:1];
        NSString *letter2 = [obj2[0] substringToIndex:1];
        return [letter1 compare:letter2];
    }];
```

It's not the most efficient solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve some what as :

```
NSArray *rows1 = @[
                       @"Adam Harris",
                       @"Devraj Singh",
                       @"Devraj Singh",
                       @"Er Devraj Gurjar",
                       @"Ghh HHS",
                       @"Mark Json",
                       @"Ninehertz India",
                       @"Ninehertz India",
                       @"Test User",
                       @"Test Test",
                       @"Yatin TFT"
                       ];

    NSArray *sortedArray = [rows1 sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    //make keys and store
    for (NSString *str in sortedArray) {
        NSString *key = [str substringToIndex:1];

        //store the str if this is first object
        if (dict[key]== nil ) {
            NSArray *arr = @[str];
            [dict setObject:arr forKey:key];
        }
        //if there is another get the array and add more
        else{
            NSMutableArray *arr = [dict[key] mutableCopy];
            [arr addObject:str];
            [dict setObject:arr forKey:key];
        }

    }
    NSLog(@"Dict: %@",dict);
```